# Parse, ShareKit and the FacebookSDK - 30 Duplicate Symbols

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, sharekit, parse-platform

Im trying to add Parse to a current App that I have. It already has ShareKit included, which has parts (?) of the FacebookSDK included as a submodule.
 It also requires me to have the Linker Flags: **-ObjC -all_load**

To make Parse work with this, I need to include the FacebookSDK, which I'm doing. But as soon as I do that, I run into an issue with the duplicates while compiling.

Any idea how I can work around that?

Similar error was found here:
  https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/issues/731

I cant remove the FacebookSDK.framework tough, as I need it for Parse to compile with the -ObjC -all_load flag.

Edit:

This is the complete Error:

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBRequest._url in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBRequest.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBRequest.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBRequest._connection in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBRequest.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBRequest.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBRequest._responseText in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBRequest.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBRequest.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBRequest._error in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBRequest.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBRequest.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBRequest._delegate in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBRequest.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBRequest.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBRequest._state in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBRequest.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBRequest.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBRequest.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBRequest.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBRequest in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBRequest.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBRequest.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLoginDialog._loginDelegate in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBLoginDialog.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBLoginDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_FBLoginDialog in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBLoginDialog.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBLoginDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBLoginDialog in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBLoginDialog.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBLoginDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._orientation in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._webView in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._modalBackgroundView in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._loadingURL in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._delegate in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._showingKeyboard in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._closeButton in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._spinner in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._params in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._serverURL in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_FBDialog in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBDialog in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Facebook._requests in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/Facebook.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Facebook.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Facebook._fbDialog in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/Facebook.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Facebook.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Facebook._appId in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/Facebook.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Facebook.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Facebook._urlSchemeSuffix in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/Facebook.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Facebook.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Facebook._sessionDelegate in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/Facebook.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Facebook.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Facebook in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/Facebook.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Facebook.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Facebook in:
>       /Users/martinlang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Club_W-evqasilyjjnftqelkocaozbwkgyq/Build/Intermediates/Club W.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Club W.build/Objects-normal/i386/Facebook.o
>       /Users/martinlang/Development/clubw/ClubW-iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Facebook.o)
>   ld: 30 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Try without -all_load.

Comment: Wont work - I also need the -all_load for ShareKit and RestKit - I read something, that I could use -force_load - trying to see how this would do the trick.

Comment: Are you using latest Xcode and did you try not using it?

Comment: Yes, using latest Xcode and I did try. Still failed to build with the same error.

Comment: Ok, so you don't need it but removing it isn't enough. What exactly is the compile error?

Comment: Try this: http://binaryfinery.wordpress.com/2010/06/11/universal-static-library-problem-in-iphone-sdk/

Comment: Added the complete error.

Answer (score 0):

Delete you FacebookSDK from your framework because ShareKit already provide it when you install it using pods